# In Scala getting a list from certain items of a different list or file respectivly

Tags: list, scala

first of all I am new to this site and Scala, so please excuse any mistakes :)

Let's say I have a file with numbers in it that are seperated by commas like this: 12,25,32...

I want these numbers in a List (in the same order they are in the file!). My problem is that, when i read the contents of the File and convert it to a list by using:

```
val myList = Source.fromFile("fileWithNumbers").toList
```

I end up with each digit and the commas beeing a single item. In order to get what I want, I came up with the following function:

```
def numsfromlist(a: List[Char], res: List[Int], temp: String) : List[Int] =  {
if(a.isEmpty)
    res.reverseenter code here
else if(a.head == ',' )
    numsfromlist(a.tail, temp.toInt :: res, "")
else 
    numsfromlist( a.tail, res, temp :+ a.head)}
```

which I then call like this

```
val tailres = numsfromlist(Source.fromFile("fileWithNumbers").toList, Nil, "")
```

But I figured there must be a nicer, more scala-like way to do it. I'd appreciate the help. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do for example:

```
val s = Source.fromFile("fileWithNumbers")
val nums = for {
  line <- s.getLines
  num  <- line.split(',')
} yield num.toInt
```

This will get you all the numbers of all the lines in a single list. Note that it will throw an exception if you there is a string that cannot be converted to an `Int`.

Comment: I think you meant `line.split(',').map(_.toInt)`

Comment: Hey, thx for the quick answer. The problem is that alle the numbers are in one single line. Sorry, that i didn't mention that earlier... BTW what does map(_.toInt) do exactly and how does it work?